# Cannot show data in the page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore to store my data. I following code to retrieve data from firestore

```js
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await database.collection('jobs').get()
            setJobs(data.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

and in my return statement, I have

```js
<Row className="row-grid">
   {jobs.map(job => {
     <h1>Test</h1>
   }
</Row>
```

However, `Test` is not being shown on the page. I even changed from `<h1>Test</h1>` to `console.log(job)` and I am able to see all the content and job has data. But I am not able to figure why the header tag or any HTML tags show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must `return` the map function if you're gonna open curly braces.